# Parameter transfer between different object types

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, std-function

I would like to transfer some parameters from one object to another. The object are of different types. I tried some ways but none of them compiled. All types are given and cannot be changed.

I wanted to use `std::bind`, `std::function`, `std::mem_fn` and/or lambdas. But I didn't find correct mixture of these.

Is there a way to write a template function do this?

(Visual Studio 2017)

```
#include <functional>

class Type1 {};
class Type2 {};
class Type3 {};

class A
{
public:
    bool getter( Type1& ) const { return true; }
    bool getter( Type2& ) const { return true; }
    bool getter( Type3&, int index = 0 ) const { return true; }
};

class B
{
public:
    bool setter( const Type1& ) { return true; }
    bool setter( const Type2& ) { return true; }
    bool setter( const Type3& ) { return true; }
    bool setter( const Type3&, int ) { return true; }
};

void test()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    // Instead of this:
    Type3 data;
    if ( a.getter( data ) )
    {
        b.setter( data );
    }

    // I need something like this (which the same as above):
    function( a, A::getter, b, B::setter );
};
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you want `function` to do. If it's just to transfer a `Type3` specifically, there is no obvious point to it. If you want it to handle different getter/setter pairs, you need to specify which one somehow. If you want it to handle all pairs, you need to enumerate them.

Comment: what you want function to do? Why are you marking templates tag if you're not using them? Instead of what you wanted to use why don't you focus in what you would need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is what you really want, but

```
template <typename T3, typename T1, typename T2>
void function(const T1& t1, bool(T1::*getter)(T3&) const,
              T2& t2, bool(T2::*setter)(const T3&))
{
    T3 data;
    if ((t1.*getter)(data))
    {
        (t2.*setter)(data);
    }
}
```

With usage similar to

```
function<Type3>(a, &A::getter, b, &B::setter);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d90366a98d599df2)

Note: I removed `int index = 0`.

Comment: I think I tried it (or something very similar) already. But unfortunately it gives an error with VS2017:
error C2872: 'function': ambiguous symbol
note: could be 'void function(const T1 &,bool (__cdecl T1::* )(T3 &) const,T2 &,bool (__cdecl T2::* )(const T3 &))'

Comment: yes I saw and tried that in the on-line demo, but VS2017 doesn't like it.

Comment: Sorry. It was a name conflict. It works fine. Thanks for the advice.